# How can I find the angle of a rotated object in Modelica?

Tags: oop, modeling, angle, modelica, openmodelica

This is my block diagram of the system:

[image: Graphical model]

Applying a force to the body in one axis causes it to rotate like this:

[image: Animation of result]

I am trying to be able to see, on a plot perhaps or just a simple angle sensor, what the angle of the object is at 100 seconds.

I tried using an angle sensor but couldn't work out where to connect it (I have very basic Modelica skills).

Comment: Does Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Sensors.AbsoluteAngles suffice your needs ?